# How to change the colour of a column based on a condition in pug

Tags: javascript, pug

I have the below lines of code in which I want to change the colour of all pending columns when they have a value greater than zero and if they have the value equal to zero no change in background.The below is my code in which I am trying to use if condition and change the background but it is not working for me.

code:

```
mixin dispatch-summary(dispatched)
  - var count = 0
  table
    caption.align-center.font-bold.heading DISPATCHED RECORDS
      tr
        th.align-center.font-bold S.NO
        th.align-center.font-bold.diswidth Dispatch Id
        th.align-center.font-bold.prjwidth Projects
        th.align-center.font-bold.rescol Total Boxes
        th.align-center.font-bold.rescol Total Pending Boxes
        th.align-center.font-bold.rescol Total Panel Boxes
        th.align-center.font-bold.rescol Total Pending Panel Boxes
        th.align-center.font-bold.rescol Total Hardware Boxes
        th.align-center.font-bold.rescol Total Pending Hardware Boxes
        th.align-center.font-bold.rescol Total Parts 
        th.align-center.font-bold.rescol Total Pending Parts
        th.align-center.font-bold.rescol Total Hardware
        th.align-center.font-bold.rescol Total Pending Hardware



        each task in dispatched
          -var dispatch_id = task.dispatch_id
          -var project = task.project
          -var total_boxes = task.total_boxes
          -var total_dispatched_boxes = task.total_dispatched_boxes
          -var pending_boxes = total_boxes-total_dispatched_boxes
          -var total_panel_boxes = task.total_panel_boxes
          -var total_dispatched_panel_boxes = task.total_dispatched_panel_boxes
          -var pending_panel_boxes = total_panel_boxes-total_dispatched_panel_boxes
          -var total_hardware_boxes = task.total_hardware_boxes
          -var total_dispatched_hardware_boxes = task.total_dispatched_hardware_boxes
          -var pending_hardware_boxes=total_hardware_boxes-total_dispatched_hardware_boxes
          -var total_parts = task.total_parts
          -var total_dispatched_parts = task.total_dispatched_parts
          -var pending_parts = total_parts-total_dispatched_parts
          -var total_hardware = task.total_hardware
          -var total_dispatched_hardware = task.total_dispatched_hardware
          -var pending_hardware = total_hardware-total_dispatched_hardware

          tr(bgcolor='#c3d9f0')
            td.font-bold=++count
            td.align-left= dispatch_id
            td.align-left= project
            td.align-left= total_boxes
            -if(pending_boxes > 0)
              td.align-left.text-color= pending_boxes
            -else
              td.align-left= pending_boxes
            td.align-left= total_panel_boxes
            td.align-left= pending_panel_boxes
            td.align-left= total_hardware_boxes
            td.align-left= pending_hardware_boxes
            td.align-left= total_parts
            td.align-left= pending_parts
            td.align-left= total_hardware
            td.align-left= pending_hardware
```

Following is my JSON data:

```
{ dispatched: 
   [ { dispatch_id: 6433,
       dispatched: true,
       project: '001940_N',
       current_panel_boxes: 0,
       current_hardware_boxes: 1,
       total_parts: 750,
       total_dispatched_parts: 0,
       total_hardware: 7805,
       total_dispatched_hardware: 36,
       total_boxes: 89,
       total_dispatched_boxes: 1,
       total_panel_boxes: 66,
       total_hardware_boxes: 23,
       total_dispatched_hardware_boxes: 1,
       total_dispatched_panel_boxes: 0 },
     { dispatch_id: 6435,
       dispatched: true,
       project: '002051_N,002052_D,002054_N',
       current_panel_boxes: 2,
       current_hardware_boxes: 1,
       total_parts: 2,
       total_dispatched_parts: 2,
       total_hardware: 1,
       total_dispatched_hardware: 1,
       total_boxes: 3,
       total_dispatched_boxes: 3,
       total_panel_boxes: 2,
       total_hardware_boxes: 1,
       total_dispatched_hardware_boxes: 1,
       total_dispatched_panel_boxes: 2 } ],
  pendingDispatch: [] }
```

Comment: Can you post your JSON data here please?

Comment: I posted the JSON data@ Gibin Ealias

Comment: Thanks. Did you try my solution below?

Comment: yeah but not working

Comment: Can you post the compiled HTML code along with your css too?

Comment: I am not using html and css

Comment: Basically your pug will be compiled to HTML and you would also have a css file for your classes `text-color` or `align-left` to work. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the compiled HTML element.

```
<tr bgcolor="#c3d9f0">
  ...
  <div class="text-color">
    <td class="align-left">1</td>
  </div>
  ....
</tr>
```

The above structure is invalid as we can't have a `<div>` as a direct child of `<tr>`

Now, as a solution to your specific issue on changing the `background-color` you may use the below lines of code,

```
-if(pending_boxes > 0)
  td.align-left.text-color= pending_boxes
-else
  td.align-left= pending_boxes
```

Which when the condition gets true will compile to,

```
<td class="align-left text-color">1</td>
```

Hope this helps.